determining if odds-ratio for a numerical x variable and binary y label in logistic regression differs between groups (ie. gender or race)
I've seen people ask a similar question, but I'm still not super clear what the best recommendation would be - I am looking at a binary dependent variable, and multiple independent variables (some of which are categorical, such as race or sex or other demographic variables, and some of which are numerical). How can I determine if the association / odds-ratio between a numerical variable x1 and binary y is different between different sex groups,  or different race groups. I'm curious about looking at the difference from doing simple logistic regression (just the x1 as the dependent), and from doing multiple logistic regression (with x as well as the other categorical/numerical demographic variables that have been one-hot-encoded with the largest category of each variable dropped as the reference).
What is the best way to analyze this? Would splitting the population into the groups (ie. female patients vs male patients, or White vs Black vs Asian patients) and running logistic regression for each to compare the odds-ratios be a bad approach? Chi-squared testing? Others? Much appreciate any recommendations/explanations.

Hey @mz., welcome to CV. As a simple start, you could try fitting a model (e.g. say if you want to see if the effect of x on y differs by sex) with an x:sex interaction term, and see if the coefficient for that is significant. You could also fit a multiple models with different interaction terms e.g. model 1 has x:race, model 2 x:sex etc., and use AIC to compare them
